# Как из кода вызвать нажатие на поле QLineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, курсор, qlineedit

мне нужно сделать так, чтобы курсор после клика на ячейку `QTableWidget` оставался/становился на `QLineEdit` и продолжался ввод в данный виджет. Можно ли это сделать через QFocusEvent?

```
    def item_click(self, row, column):
    #ф-ция вызывается при клике на ячейку
        row = row + 1
        column = self.alphabet[column]
    #получаю айди ячейки (айди выглядит так: 'A1')

        txt = self.lineEdit.text()
        if txt:
        #если вводится айди ячейки, от которой будет зависеть наша ячейка
            self.lineEdit.setText(f'{txt} {column}{row}')
        else:
        #иначе, нам ввели айди ячейки в которую будет присвоено какое-то 
        выражение
            self.lineEdit.setText(f'{column}{row} = ')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]  и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: я хочу сделать электронную таблицу, похожую на эксель, ввод в ячейку у меня производится через QLineEdit,  кликом на ячейку, я пишу айди(номер) ячейки в QLineEdit, и чтобы пользователю после каждого клика по ячейке не нажимать на QLineEdit, дабы переключить курсор, я хочу из кода вызывать нажатие на QLineEdit

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: все что мог указал выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашел решение в функции setFocus()

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

попробуй .setCursor(). должно помочь.

Comment: я пробовал, но у меня не получилось реализовать то, что нужно

Comment: подскажи, пожалуйста, если знаешь как

Comment: насколько я понял, тебе нужно после вызова этой функции вернуть курсор на QLineEdit. значит просто поставь self.{имя твоего QLineEdit}.setCursor() в начале функции.

Comment: TypeError: setCursor(self, Union[QCursor, Qt.CursorShape]): not enough arguments

Comment: если указать все нужные аргументы, то все равно получится не то, что нужно

Comment: прошу прощения: .setCursorPosition(0)

Comment: пробовал, тоже не спасает

Comment: значит я не правильно понял вопрос, так как у меня курсор устанавливается после команды.

Comment: мне нужно сделать так, чтобы курсор после клика на ячейку QTableWidget оставался/становился на QLineEdit и продолжался ввод в QLineEdit